# Windows Phone Application under Games

Tags: c#, windows-phone

i have created a windows phone game but i started the project as an application. Now, how can I make it appear in the Xbox Game category? Do I have to create again the project? I hope not!

Answer (score 1):

While you're developing your app/game, it will be listed with the other apps on your phone. When you publish it you will be asked to which category it belongs, so you will choose games (and whatever subcategory). It is only after downloading it from the games section in the Marketplace that if will show up in your Xbox Games menu.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that because I created it as an application it wouldn't have been in Games!

Comment: I had the same worry for my first game. I wasted two days trying to figure out how to get it into the Xbox Games menu. After publishing, I downloaded it as a test and it shows up in the right place. (Actually, the dev version is still there so I've got two copies on the phone now, one in Xbox Games, and one in the regular app list).